# How does Bash manage its memory?

Tags: bash, memory-management

For example, if I declare a variable `a=8`:

- Where is it stored? in the running process heap?
- When does it get free?
- Who's responsible for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bash variables like

```
a=8
```

are stored as heap memory, and they are never removed unless the user explicitly `unset` the variable -- so in essence the user is responsible for deleting it if it ever needs deleting.

In bash 2.05 variables are internally managed through a hash table, where memory for the hash table is obtained and release by "malloc" and "free".  The removing of the elements from the hash table does not immediately remove the element from the hash table, but it is cleaned up through a garbage collection `flush_hash_table` that is called at key points in the execution.

Bash [version 4.4](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.4.tar.gz) have a re-written some of the hash tables, and the `flush_hash_table` no longer exist, but is replaced with a function`hash_flush`.

Hence different versions and port could behave differently and you should not rely on that the memory is actually immediately released even if you do an `unset`, or expect any particular behavior of memory when writing shell scripts

Answer (score 3):

Memory management isn't something you need to concern yourself with in any shell language. Suffice it to say, `bash` is responsible for the allocation and deallocation of any memory used.

*All* interpreted languages store their variables on the heap; even if they use a stack, that is dynamically allocated on the interpreter's heap as well.

Comment: @ManoMini it's not nice to want to downvote answers to your own questions... At least the answer is not _wrong_.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre -- it is not answering the question, it is the equivalent of saying "These are not the droids you are looking for"

Comment: I was just pointing out that OP rarely answers aggressively like that. "if I had a gun I'd shoot you" could be the next step :) OP obviously lacks experience with this site. That's why downvote rep is there (not high enough IMHO).

Comment: Now, notice how the downvote was "corrected" (not by me), by someone else finding that too much: opposite effect of what the downvoter wanted.

Comment: Here's the thing: `bash`, like all interpreted languages, really only have one place to store *anything*: the heap.

Comment: It is still not an answer to the question -- and why do you assume the OP was the one who downvoted it?

Comment: @Soren: OP did _not_ downvote, he told he will come back here and downvote when he gets the rep!! BTW OP could upvote your question, he didn't (yet). Do the math: chepner got 8 points out of this you got 0, and a lot of questions to answer to...

Comment: (Sigh) yep I could try to chase the point, badges and hats -- but don't actually care -- @chepner -- why didn't you just answer your question with that "all interpreted languages must store stuff on heap"